# [function.fsockopen]: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known

Tags: host, serversocket, fsockopen

I have some problem with fsock open , but i am newbie on PHP about sockets.

the warning of my script is :

```
Warning: fsockopen() [function.fsockopen]: 
php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known
```

and this my script :

```
            foreach($extend as $extra => $serv) {                       
                    $buffers = NULL;      
                    if ($socket = fsockopen($serv[0], 43)
                    /* lets we show system can't connect the server */
                    or die('error connect servers' . $socket));
                    fputs($socket, $vers.$extra . "\r\n");

                            while( !feof($socket) )
                            {
                                    $buffers .= fgets($socket,128);
                            }

                    fclose($socket);
```